# Add a method hook that fires after any activerecord method on a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

One of our use cases involves publishing active record models over Drb. It looks like when we do this we are inadvertently leaving connections checked out and as a result we're receiving AR timeouts.

I think this is because of this comment in the active record code:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html

Specifically

> "Simply use ActiveRecord::Core#connection as with Active Record 2.1
>   and earlier (pre-connection-pooling). Eventually, when you're done
>   with the connection(s) and wish it to be returned to the pool, you
>   call ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!. This will be the
>   default behavior for Active Record when used in conjunction with
>   Action Pack's request handling cycle."

When we're accessing out models over Drb we're not going through the request cycle so the connection is not getting checked back in.

The same document suggests we need to check these connections back in manually - what I need is a way to hook into all methods on a published model and call "ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections" afterwards.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

   #I need this method to be called after every method on this class!
   def close_connections
     ActiveRecord::Base.close_active_connections
   end

end
```

Closing the connections manually isn't really an option because there are tens of thousands of lines of code and I'd need to go and add "close the connection" after every single one!

Answer (score 1):

You could add this snippet at the end of your class definition..

```
(instance_methods - Class.new.methods).each do |method|
   define_method "#{method}_with_close_connections" do |*args, &block|
     self.send "#{method}_without_close_connections", *args, &block
     ActiveRecord::Base.close_active_connections
   end
   alias_method_chain method, :close_connections
end
```

Highly non-recommended, however. You should probably find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to use Observers - http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html

You will, however, need an observer for each one of your Models.

Before going down this path though, I would thoroughly evaluate your implementation and find a better way of accessing the connection pool.